# How to Strip File Name using SED

Tags: linux, sed, filenames

I have a variable `g_inboundDir`  which contains the value '/tmp/AI_INBOUND'.
Now, I need to read the files in the directory pointed by the variable  'g_inboundDir'  and then work with the files. Directory '/tmp/AI_INBOUND' contains files a.pdf, b.pdf c.pdf etc.

NOTE:  I do not want to change my current directory to '/tmp/AI_INBOUND'

I have written following code:

```
for i in `ls ${g_inboundDir}/*.pdf 2>/dev/null`
do
    j=`echo $i | sed   "s/${g_inboundDir}//"`;
    echo $j;
done;
```

I was expecting `echo $j` will give me the file name but I am getting an error in sed command.

Comment: You are facing errors as g_inboundDir has slashes which are clashing with the slashes in the sed command itself. You need to escape the slashes + any other chars which might be meaningful to sed for it to work. Else, you may see my post below.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to reach for `sed` for this:

```
for i in "${g_inboundDir}"/*.pdf
do
   echo "${i##*/}"; # will give u the filename
   # aliter:
   echo "${i}" | sed -e 's|.*/||' ;# will give the filename via sed as u wanted
done
```

Comment: One question I have is: What is | doing after s in the sed command 's|.*/||'

Comment: sed is bright, whatever comes AFTER the s in a sed command is used to separate search-replace. s@.*/@@ would work just as s;.*/;; or s#.*/##.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `ls ${g_inboundDir}/*.pdf 2>/dev/null`
do
    basename $i
done
```

Comment: Why parse `ls`? `for i in ${g_inboundDir}/*.pdf` would work just as well (in fact, better).